# New Data Breakpoint disabled in Visual Studio 2008 mixed project

Tags: visual-studio-2008, breakpoints

In a DLL invoked from C++/CLI code I don't seem able to set Data Breakpoints in some pure C code. The menu option *New Data Breakpoint...* is disabled as is the popup in the breakpoints window. I haven't been able to find anyone else reporting this, the only [similar experience](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/fr-FR/vcgeneral/thread/0ce702d6-5428-4b9b-8113-7fa3afe5b66f) is for a Mobile developer.

Debugging is otherwise working fine - I can set Watches and breakpoints on functions.

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 Professional sp1 on Vista x64.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think that setting data breakpoints is only available if you are debugging in native mode. It is not available in managed mode, or mixed mode debugging.

Comment: I have since written a pure Win32 application to invoke the DLL and found that I can use data breakpoints in that, so I agree, sadly, with your opinion.